# "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" New to coding and trying to learn, but here is what I tried

Tags: google-colaboratory

This is the error I am getting:

```
  File "<ipython-input-30-56bb89b51cc1>", line 4
    pass = 50 #@param {type:"integer"}
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am using a Google Colab for VQGAN+CLIP AI Text to Image Generation: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1go6YwMFe5MX6XM9tv-cnQiSTU50N9EeT?usp=sharing
and the code with the error is not included in the Colab, but is found here: https://tuscriaturas.miraheze.org/wiki/Ayuda:Generar_im%C3%A1genes_con_VQGAN%2BCLIP/English#Code_for_generating_the_zip
The default code is supposed to save every 50th image to a .zip automatically. Deleting the line that gives the error saves every single image, which in this particular case is 1,350 images. I tried looking up this issue, but my lack of knowledge doesn't help and I can't find an example of this exact issue. I tried changing 'pass' to 'intervals' thinking that would work for some reason and it just ignored that line entirely. I hope I gave enough detail and I apologize if this is a stupid issue but I am trying to learn and have hit a wall. I appreciate any help. Here is the code for the entire cell.

```
# @title Create a zip with all of the images (or some)
initial_image = 0 #@param {type:"integer"}
final_image = 1350 #@param {type:"integer"}
pass = 50 #@param {type:"integer"}
filename = "files.zip" #@param {type:"string"}

import zipfile

if final_image == -1:
  final_image = i

zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
for i in tqdm(range(initial_image, final_image+1)):
  fname = f"{i:04}.png"
  zipf.write(f"steps/{fname}", f"{filename.split('.')[0]}-{fname}")
zipf.close()
print(filename, "created. Downloading… A download dialog will be open when the download is ready.")
from google.colab import files
files.download(filename)
```

Comment: If you run a script with only the four assignments at the top of your script and no other content, does it have the same error? (If so, I wonder if you have a non-ASCII character that _looks like_ a `=` but isn't one; it's easy to get that kind of thing if you copied-and-pasted code from the web / a Word document / a PDF / etc instead of typing it directly in a tool designed as a programmer's editor).

Comment: BTW, trying to come up with the smallest possible code segment that isolates your problem doesn't just help you troubleshoot it yourself -- it also helps you comply with our rules, which require a [mre]. Note the "minimal" part of that definition: If you can produce the same problem with code that doesn't require someone to have your `files.zip` or to use colab at all, then it's _obligatory_ to do just that.